# Apache FOP - strange image in PDF export

Tags: java, image, pdf, apache-fop

Code is generating PDF document using Apache FOP library(0.93 version).
Some  images are displaying strange in PDF. You can check attached screenshot.
The image is normal jpg.
Have you any idea which can be the reason of this?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing a piece of code it's difficult to spot the problem, but you could try to enforce a certain size and position to get the desired effect.

Comment: Could you give more details about this? Like, provide a sample FO file and the affected images?

One thing I would check is if the problematic images have an embedded resolution (DPI) that is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

first, I would suggest you upgrade to FOP 1.0 [1], since 0.93 is now over five years old; if that doesn't fix it, then you can try one of the more recent dev builds [2] or send email to [3]

[1] http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/index.html

[2] http://ci.apache.org/projects/xmlgraphics/fop/snapshots/

[3] mailto:fop-users@xmlgraphics.apache.org

note that a new maintenance release FOP 1.1 is expected within the next month